# Local and maximal solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Consider the Cauchy problem $(E)$: $x'(r)=f(r,x(r))$ with initial condition $x_0.$

If we proved that there exists an increasing sequence $(r_k)_k$ such that $r_0=0,$ for every $k,(E)$ has unique (local) solution over $[0,r_k[,$ then does is lead to a maximal solution?